# Raspberry pi not reading sd cards

Tags: raspbian-buster

I got my raspberry pi new model 3b+ just last year, and it worked normally, but after what might have happened to be some failure with the pi that it got removed from its power source, it stopped working. only the red light glows, and normally too, which means there's nothing wrong with the power supply, but the green light isn't working, which means no action is taking place in it.

i removed the card, then turned it back on, the green light did not flash. I even did it the way that i removed the card first, then disconnected the power supply, then turned it on. So i downloaded the bootloader, even the old one, repeatedly on a separate sd-card on FAT32 . Still nothing. Then I was checking that since it got shut down improperly, it might have crashed its os.

i even downloaded raspbian again, still doesn't work. the micro sd card is good, because if it wasn't i couldn't have formatted it. I tried everything i could, and it doesn't work. I am fairly sure nothing wrong with the pi's other components, what i think is that something's wrong with the sd card reader. But i see nothing wrong with it either(Like when i see it from the outside).

It might not be reading it, but i want to make sure that that is the problem, so i am checking everything else first. It has the pins at the top-right connected, when i put the card in. pls tell what might be wrong with the pi. I seriously searched for a month now with the pi not working.

Comment: Try paragraphs - then people may be inclined to read

Comment: What software did you use?

Comment: i used raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

If the green light is not on there is definitely a problem with the SD Card. The only things you can do are try a different SD card and reformat the one you are currently using. If neither of those work, it would seem to be a hardware issue. In that case it is much more worthwhile to get a new Pi rather than trying to fix it yourself since the Pi is so cheap.

Comment: i'll try a new sd card. i did reformat it even after a re uploaded recovery file on another but what i really think the problem is is the micro sd card reader.so if there's a way to fix that pls tell me how that can be fixed. i think i'll have to replace the pi if i can't fix the reader

Comment: The issue with trying to repair it is you don't know exactly what components are not working. While you can find out if you spend enough time analyzing raspberry pi schematics and testing your pi, but most people find its a better use of their time (and money if you don't already have the proper equipment) to buy a new pi. However, I did read about the Pi being able to boot from USB, while I have not tried that myself, you could look into that, here is one discussion of the topic https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=198258

Comment: Yes I know it is easy but first you have to enable that option and I don't think it is with mine.and about the sd card, if it really was corrupt could it have been formatted?

Comment: You should be able to, corrupt just means the data is unreadable. If the card was damaged it would be a different story. If it formatted the card may be fine

Comment: i bought a new sd card and flashed that.NOT Working. i tried adding lines of booting with usb in config.txt, didn't work. is there any way to download the bootloader, because its should be that now

Comment: Also, here is something.i tried something in which i removed everything including the sd card, then turned it on. No green light flashed. it says on the site that this means that the SPI EEPROM is corrupted?how to fix this the above comment came because of me finding this